# Clone an elasticsearch docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, copy

I have the following setup:

- one es-docker (live)
- one es-docker (working)

So i wish that the working docker can run some data changes and save this inside the es application. (This changes will run over a few hours).

After this changes are done i wish to copy the working-docker (with all data) and override the live-docker.

So i can run the changes over some hours without having a downtime on live (or a minimalistic downtime).

But i don't know how to "copy" the original included all data.

Thank you for your hints.

Comment: If you want to solve this using 2 separate clusters running in docker, you could use a blue-green deployment strategy. Or Elasticsearch itself provides a means for doing this directly in a single cluster, with the use of aliases, and you don't need 2 separate clusters. Which solution are you most interested in?

Answer (score 1):

The Elasticsearch Definitive Guide [outlines a process to achieve zero downtime](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/index-aliases.html) for use cases like yours, making use of [Index Aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html).

The idea is to create an Index Alias that your applications will always use to access the live data.

Given an alias named "alias1" that is pointing to an index named "index1", perform the following steps:

1. Create a new index, named "index2"
2. Run your batch indexing process
3. Swap "alias1" to point to "index2"
4. Clean up "index1"

The alias swapping occurs in a single call, and Elasticsearch performs the action atomically, giving you the zero downtime you desire. The call looks something like this:

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index" : "index1", "alias" : "alias1" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "index2", "alias" : "alias1" } }
    ]
}
```